# How to sum at once in loop without waiting?

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-5.3, bigdata

My view blade like this :

```
...
@foreach($orders as $order)
    ...
    <td>{{ $order->sumTotal['total'] }}</td>
    ...
@endforeach
...
```

My model like this :

```
public function getSumTotalAttribute()
{
    $total = Order::where('year','=', '2017')
                  ->sum('total');
    return ['total'=>$total];
}
```

If I have 1 data order in `$orders` array, it will spent 4 second to display data

If I have 10 data order in `$orders` array, it will spent 4 second x 10 data order = 40 second to display data

It's so long

How long if I has an 1 thousand of data?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Make the columns you're using in your `where` indexed in the db. That will speed things up.

Comment: @techfoobar, Great. Thanks a lot. Now, it's faster

Comment: @techfoobar, I use mongodb. I try sum 500 thousand of data. It spent 4 minutes. Do you think it is fast or not?

Comment: Oh! 4 minutes is way too long for any process that makes the user wait. There must be a way around. I'm not an expert in mongodb, so unable to suggest anything as of now.

Comment: @techfoobar, Seems it was not because the database. I use mysql database also get the same result